# Limiting my output with an array

Tags: java, arrays

My question has to do with counting integers in an array. This is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Frequency { 
  public static void main(String[]args) { 
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("enter numbers: ");
    int[] arr = new int[51]; 
    for(int i = 0; true; i++) { 
      int in = kbd.nextInt(); 
      if(in < 0)break; 
      else if(in > 50)break; 
      else arr[in]++; 
    } 
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
      System.out.println(i+" occurrences of "+arr[i]); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

The way the problem outputs is correct except I need some way of filtering out all the numbers that have an occurrence of 0 so that only numbers that were in the input show in the output; instead of every number between 0 and 50.

Comment: So you need to skip `0`, print `1-9`, skip `10`, print `11-19`, etc?

Comment: @nhgrif OP holds an array of counters for numbers between 0 and 49. Looks like he/she wants to print those numbers which counter is not 0.

Comment: Yea, I was just about to delete my comment after rereading the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already written an `if` statement, to stop your first loop when user enters a negative number. Simply write the same thing for your second loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
  if (arr[i] > 0) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]+" occurrences of "+i); 
  }
}
```

*Side-note: I have also swapped `arr[i]` and `i`*

Comment: I think OP wants to know if the original array contains `i`, not if `arr[i] > 0`.

Comment: When the user types a number, he is clearly incrementing `arr[in]`. Thus, `arr[i] = j` means *`j` occurrences of `i`*. Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, I was the one missing the `arr[in]++` line and causing myself all sorts of confusion. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        if(!(i==0 || i%10==0) && arr[i]!=0)
      System.out.println(i+" occurrences of "+arr[i]); 
    }
```